# quarkus with json-b and private property visibility

Tags: quarkus

In json-b, I can use a custom `PropertyVisibilityStrategy`. What is the behaviour for quarkus if I use the following:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import javax.json.bind.config.PropertyVisibilityStrategy;

/**
 * Enables private property visibility 
 * and disables method visibility for JSON-B processings.
 */
public final class PrivateVisibilityStrategy implements PropertyVisibilityStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean isVisible(Field field) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isVisible(Method method) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then on a class I can use

```
@JsonbVisibility(value = PrivateVisibilityStrategy.class)
public class User {
// only fields are used for json mappings because of "PrivateVisibilityStrategy"
..
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Will quarkus use reflection for such cases (because it must use field access)?
2. If yes, should I avoid such cases in quarkus to avoid reflection to improve performance?
3. Should I always avoid field access in quarkus by reflections? Or does quarkus use `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles` for such cases behind the scene?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using a class like this:

```
@Singleton
public class JsonConfigurator implements JsonbConfigCustomizer {

    public void customize(JsonbConfig config) {
        config.withPropertyVisibilityStrategy(new PrivateVisibilityStrategy());
    }
}
```

`PrivateVisibilityStrategy`is just like you posted.